# Changing the title of a somewhat unclear question to literally say that it is an unclear question, and nothing more

Tags: discussion, editing, title, etiquette

I just saw a question with a peculiarly meta title; when I looked at it, it seemed normal enough for the most part, except the title. Turns out, a high-rep user had [rewritten just the title to describe the way the question was bad](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/55963/revisions#rev0c9fe6c9-4574-4e67-916b-0aa047b52b64).

That uh. That don't fill me with joy. Is this a thing we should be doing? (I would rollback except I seemingly can't, and I'm not entirely sure this is ♦ flag fodder.)

Comment: As a side note, you can rollback if you have 2k rep.

Comment: @MARamezani: Hmm, I thought rollbacks were available before. Maybe just for your own posts or something.

Comment: Yes...You can rollback your posts at anytime (aka without rep requirements)...iirc.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yeah, that's not really acceptable behavior.  It amounts to vandalism, and if it were a suggested edit, I'd have rejected it.

I've rolled back the edit.  If the problem persists, rather than roll back again, one of us can flag for moderator attention.

Comment: Thanks for fixing this. As a footnote, it's also okay to flag vandalism, so the O.P. could have flagged this as well.

Comment: @J.R. OK, I'll keep that in mind.